# authentication and authorization best way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

what is the best practise for building authentication and authorization layer in asp.net mvc 3 and 4 websites for medium to large sites lets say a govt application with lets say 10000 hits per day. what is the prefered method in most of the cases.

1) complete build a new layer from scratch

2) use membership provider ( can it be completely molded according to my requirements?)

3) i recently came to know about the identity and iprinciple interfaces

or any other approach.

***edit***

what approach does stackoverflow uses?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a strict **best practice** for any implementation. There are obviously strict security policies to follow for data protection etc. so whatever layer you choose will need to adhere to this. I've used ASP.Net's membership provider in the past and it can be extended to suit every requirement I've had, [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme) goes further into detail of how to create a custom membership and custom role provider.

Answer (score 0):

There are many considerations when choosing authentication, and authorization for your app - you will need to provide more information.

Typical considerations for Authentication are:

- Are the users on a corporate AD or LDAP intranet (Windows, Kerberos), or are they internet users (Membership etc)?
- Do you want to use Single Sign On (e.g. OAuth etc)
- Do you want to use Claims based identity?
- Do you want users to be 'self administrative' (e.g. forgot my password etc) or call centre administered (help desk)?

With Authorization

- Is Role based security 'good enough' (IsUserInRole), or do you require permission / operation level checks (e.g. AzMan)
- Are the roles likely to change in future (e.g. will the business process / task allocation between users change)

etc.